# Javascript create iframe set content then return it from one function

Tags: javascript

I need to create an iframe dynamically, set its html, then return it as a function so it can be called later with newAdUnit(). Right now it returns [object HTMLIFrameElement]. I'm trying to figure out a way to do this all from one function. The reason for this is I'm setting up ads that need to be loaded in dynamically. A single function would make my code a lot cleaner since I can call it in a number of different ways. Any ideas?

```html
<script>
function newAdUnit(size) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.onload = function() {
        iframe = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        var html = '<body>This is a test</body>';
        iframe.open();
        iframe.write(html);
        iframe.close();
    };
    return iframe;
}
</script>
<div id="test">
<script>document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = newAdUnit()</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be so much easy if you use **JQuery** for the current operation. The code below shows how to

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function newAdUnit(obj) {
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.onload = function() {
            iframe = iframe.contentWindow.document;
            var html = '<body>This is a test</body>';
            iframe.open();
            iframe.write(html);
            iframe.close();
        };
        $(obj).append(iframe);
    }

    newAdUnit($('#test'));
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only use `.innerHTML` when the thing you want to add is a string of HTML. However, in your case, you have a [`HTMLIFrameElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement) object, and so, you can't use `.innerHTML` in this case. Currently, Javascript is implicitly calling `.toString()` on your element object returned by `newAdUnit()`, which results in `[object HTMLIFrameElement]`.

Instead, when you want to add a node element to another element, you can use [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) like so:

```
<div id="test"></div>

<script>
  function newAdUnit(size) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.onload = function() {
      iframe = iframe.contentWindow.document;
      var html = '<body>This is a test. The size is ' + size + '</body>';
      iframe.open();
      iframe.write(html);
      iframe.close();
    };
    return iframe;
  }

  document.getElementById("test").appendChild(newAdUnit(10));
</script>
```

Comment: If StackSnippets® produce an error it's because their own iframes are overly sandboxed. In normal situations it won't cause such error, `about:blank` is quite permissive. https://jsfiddle.net/3jc0bhLp/ And if OP really needs to make it work in overly sandboxed frames à la StackSnippets®, then [they could use `srcdoc`](https://jsfiddle.net/3jc0bhLp/1/) (maybe they should anyway, with only a fallback for IE).

Comment: @Kaiido oh, I see, yeah, you're right. thanks for the comment.